# Correct way to make a request in Play Framework with a proxy server

Tags: scala, playframework, proxy

What is the correct way to make a request in Play Framework with a proxy server? Currently I am doing the follow below.

`WSRequest request = wsClient.url("someUrl");
WSProxyServer proxyServer = new DefaultWSProxyServer("ProxyAddress", "ProxyPort", nothing, nothing, nothing, nothing, nothing, nothingList);
return request.withProxyServer(proxyServer);`

This solution works, but I don't see any documentation about using a proxy server in play. Is this solution normal?

Comment: Because there is no `DefaultWSProxyServer` in PlayFramework  ( at least in Play 2.6). May be `DefaultWSProxyServer` is a custom implementation in your own code base.

Comment: in the `play.api.lib.ws` WS.scala there is a `DefaultWsProxyServer`

Comment: Which version of PlayFramework ?

Comment: 2.6 I believe, this standalone play-ws project has the Proxy I speak of https://github.com/playframework/play-ws/blob/master/play-ws-standalone/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/ws/WS.scala

Comment: I think you are using Play 2.5 - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.ws.DefaultWSProxyServer . And such things are normal. The documentation which you are talking about is there to just get you started. It can not mention all the ways in to use different components with each other. You will need to refer to API documentation to get information about all ways to use a particular components. For example for a WsRequest - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.ws.WSRequest

Comment: ok, just wanted to make sure I was approaching this correctly, are there different ways to use a proxy server with a WSRequest to your knowledge?

Comment: I was not even sure about the existence of `DefaultWsProxyServer` few minutes back. You can look through the API documentation to gain more.